# Tweaking Default behavior of jQuery BlockUI plugin

Tags: jquery, blockui

I want to change the default behvior of [jQuery BlockUI plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#overview). I want to:

1. Get rid of the white box that appears over the inactive content.
2. Avoid the `Please Wait...` message, that appears by default when the elements are blocked.
3. Display default mouse cursor (not hourglass / please wait), when it is over blocked elements.

If it is impossible to changem, then what is an appropriate way I can block elements with a gray mask over the container div.

My jQuery code is:

```
function showResult(response){
    if (response.indexOf("Submission Successful") != -1){
        $("#confirmform").css("display","block");
        $("#middle").block({css: {backgroundColor: '#E0EBEB'}});
        $("#leftside").block({css: {backgroundColor: '#E0EBEB'}});
        $("#rightside").block({css: {backgroundColor: '#E0EBEB'}});
    } else if (response.indexOf("Invalid E-mail") != -1){
        //display error, no blocking
    } else if (response.indexOf("Nothing in Box") != -1){
        //do nothing
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

And here is a screenshot of the behavior, that I'm seeing:

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

What seems to be the problem? Answers to all your questions given here are right at jQuery BlockUI page. In [FAQ](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#faq) section you can find examples, how to change default message:

```
$.blockUI.defaults.message = "Please be patient...";
```

or the overlay:

```
// use yellow overlay 
$.blockUI.defaults.overlayCSS.backgroundColor = '#ff0'; 

// make overlay more transparent 
$.blockUI.defaults.overlayCSS.opacity = .2;
```

and many more examples.

While [Options](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#options) page gives you detailed information on each of the option of BlockUI and how and when to override them.

Comment: However, the overlayCSS does not change the backgroundColor of the blocked element, which is what the OP is asking for in bullet #1, and what I was looking for as well.  What I ended up doing is .blockElement { background-color: transparent !important; } and that worked